# Error while using topcount

Tags: pivot, mdx, pentaho

I'm using the following MDX query:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Unita (libri)] ON COLUMNS,
TopCount([Anno].[Anno].Members, 10.0, [Measures].[Unita (libri)]) ON ROWS
FROM [Pubblicazioni]
```

But i always get back an error:
    Error Occurred While getting Resultset
    MDX Query Editor
    An error occurred while rendering Pivot.jsp. Please see the log for details.

I can't access the log (for some reason the server is not writing logs) but i think it's not normal to get this error with this simple query. Any ideas about?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your MDX query.  I replaced your measures and members with those from AdventureWorks cube and it worked fine. Must be something with Pentaho?

Comment: i think i have to able the log (or at least think what is wrong with it) and try to write here some more interesting errors XD

Comment: by default mondrian logs are switched off. Edit your log4j.xml file and uncomment the Mondrian appender part. Then try to repeat the query and see the mondrian.log file, it should have some useful info there.